# Python: response.status_code alway return 400 when run with google api

Tags: python, api

```
import requests
import json

# Define the API endpoint and necessary headers and parameters
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1"
# url = "https://yande.re/post/similar"

api_key = "replace with your api"
headers = {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}
params = {"type": "similar", "cx": "d47119ff66e004d6b", "key":api_key}

# Read the image file and convert it to binary
with open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\theme\\3f559715-f407-47de-8540-1cd9e4fdc56c.jpg", "rb") as f:
    image_data = f.read()

# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, data=image_data)

# Check the status code of the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('ok')
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    # Extract the relevant data from the response
    similar_images = data["similar_images"]
else:
        print(response.status_code)
        print('no')
```

what wrong with my code? My url was wrong? i alway get `no` when run it

when I try with another URL like `https://yande.re/post/similar` i get return. what was happen?

Comment: status code 400 means you are sending the wrong data to the google API.

Comment: @TanveerAhmad what should i do?

Comment: you have to check what request.post accept

Answer (score 1):

`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1` is a GET Request API. But you are trying to do POST method on this API.

Here is the sample of GET Request for this API

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={API_KEY}&cx={SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}&q={query}&start={start}"

# make the API request
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

Comment: thanks for your help. if my data is not query but image, how should i do?

Comment: You want to post a image to Google API ?

Comment: my purpose is find similar image with my image and download it so I need use image as data

Comment: Try to use Vision API , which is suitable for your requirement https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest